# Alternative HTML hyperlink inside a Chat to avoid HTML Injections?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, chat

I Have a Chat. javaScript and PHP/HTML

But i need to accept a Video 1on1 Chat session click on a link inside the chat covnersation.
But its dangerours to allow HTML Tags.
At the moment all tags are in plain format so no hyperlink with onclick event works.

Have anyone a idea?

Comment: would't you try just some kind of BBcode ? user types smtg, say `[video]` and you intercept the code, and print a pre-defined html link ? and you just allow what you want

Comment: it soudns intersting but i need the geenrated  hyperlink only for the script usage  that the chat user can accept the viideocam session and it should open a popup.

Comment: the user self should no html code using

Comment: $body = "<a href=\"\" onclick=\"javascript:videoChatAccept(".$hisid.",".$id.",".$myid.");\"><br/><center>Click to accept it</center></a>";